# How to make storyboard go to correct item in document outline when clicking on a view controller in graphical view

Tags: xcode, storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

I have a lot of view controllers in my Storyboard which makes navigation a bit difficult. When I click on a view controller or other item in the document outline, it will scroll automatically to the graphical representation of this view controller. However, when clicking on the graphical representation the document outline list does not automatically scroll to the selected item. I have to scroll through this list until I see something selected to know it is the correct one.

Is there a way to select a view controller in the graphical view, and let the document outline scroll to this view controller?

Another related annoyance is that if you filter the document outline to find the correct view controller, and click on that view controller, it will be scrolled away when you reset the filter again. Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to select a view controller in the graphical view, and let the document outline scroll to this view controller?

When clicking on an object (view controller, view, etc.) in a storyboard scene in the graphical editor in Xcode, Xcode 6 does scroll the hierarchical view so that the selected object is at least partially visible. Also, hierarchical list for that scene opens up so that you can see the object. So in the 2 years since you asked this question, at least that much has improved.

Another improvement: if you point to a view controller at the top of a storyboard scene in the graphical editor, a small view pops up with the name of the scene, which makes finding it in the list a little bit easier.

> if you filter the document outline to find the correct view controller, and click on that view controller, it will be scrolled away when you reset the filter

This also seems to have improved: the selected view controller remains visible even after clearing the search field.